# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined thrown Unit Testing Jasmine

Tags: javascript, typescript, karma-jasmine

I have this error in unit testing with jasmine:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined thrown**

My function:

```
info() {
  this.requestService.postRequest('Reports', 'getInfo', {})
   .subscribe(
    data => {
      this.places = data.places;
      this.types = data.types.filter(obj => obj.id != 20);
      this.loading = false;
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error);
      this.loading = false;
    });
  };
```

The test:

```
it('When call requestService.postRequest', () => {
  
  spyOn(component.requestService, 'postRequest').and.returnValue(of({}));
  
  component.info();
  
  expect(component.requestService.postRequest).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(component.requestService.postRequest).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` object doesn't appear to have a `types` property (or a `places` property for that matter. It looks like you need to change

```js
spyOn(component.requestService, 'postRequest').and.returnValue(of({}));
```

to

```js
spyOn(component.requestService, 'postRequest').and.returnValue(of({
  places: [],
  types: []
}));
```

Comment: Please mark this answer as the correct answer if it solves the problem. :)